# Using Gradle with R project

Tags: r, gradle

I am beginning work on a project that makes heavy use of R. I've used R in the past, but only in a casual mode, whereas I'm now interested in following a more rigid practice of test/source control/continuous integration. I'm hoping to use Gradle with this project if possible, but I can't find any evidence that it is possible to use Gradle with R. Is it possible to create an R project with Gradle, and if so, where can I find steps to help me get started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be a third-party plugin (https://github.com/jamiefolson/gradle-plugin-r). Alternatively, if R provides some command-line tools or Ant tasks, you can call into them from Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

We have been working on gradle-R-plugin. (link to source is here https://github.com/arekbee/gradle-R-plugin). We have used it for CI/CD with TeamCity. gradle-R-plugin is base on devtools R package. I am happy to help you with this plugin.